# Spring OAuth2 JWT additional information and scopes

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, scopes

I have 2 questions about spring jwt token?
The first one is related to the additional informations of the JWT token:
- Is there any way to hide the additional informations from the oauth2 jwt token because they are in plain text and the same informations are duplicated in the JWT access token or payload

```
public class CustomTokenEnhancer extends JwtAccessTokenConverter {
        @Override
        public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
            final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();    
                    User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
                    additionalInfo.put("organization", user.getOwnerId());
                    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
            return accessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

The second one concerns the mapping of my user permissions to access token scopes, in fact, when i add the scopes as additional informations, which represent for my case the different permissions for a given user, and when I want to test this in my WS by @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') and #oauth2.hasScope('XXXXX')") annotation. It does not work because the checking is based on client scopes rather than user access token scopes? Is there a way, for using access token scopes (which represents my permissions user) rather than client scopes by using the #oauth2.hasScope('XXXXX') annotation? how can i do that?

thanks.